# loop doesn't break up when receiving data from client even i wrote break

Tags: python-3.x

Hi everyone I decided to create a program that transfer files between client and server, but the problem is the loop won't break its looks like he's still waiting for data to receive, even I wrote (if not data: break)
I received the file successfully, but it's not back to the outer loop any help and thank you.

```
while True:
###server side
cmd = input("enter msg command :")
client_socket.send(cmd.encode())
if cmd.startswith("download"):
    filename = cmd.strip("download ")
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        print("Downloading file...")
        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            f.write(data)
        print("Successfully downloaded")`
 #####clientside
while True:
 command = s.recv(1024)
 command = command.decode()
 if command.startswith("download"):
    print("True\n")
    filename = command.strip("download ")
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        print("file sending.....")
        while True:
           data = f.read(4096)
           if not data:
             break
           s.sendall(data)
        print("file has sent")
```

Comment: You need to post some minimal code?

Comment: server code while True:
    cmd = input("enter msg command :")
    client_socket.send(cmd.encode())
# server side
    if cmd.startswith("download"):
        filename = cmd.strip("download ")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            print("Downloading file...")
            while True:
                data = client_socket.recv(4096)
                if not data:
                    break

                f.write(data)
            print("Successfully downloaded")

Comment: while True:
     command = s.recv(1024)
     command = command.decode()
     if command.startswith("download"):
        print("True\n")
        filename = command.strip("download ")
        with open(filename,'rb') as f:
            print("file sending.....")
            while True:
               data = f.read(4096)
               if not data:
                 break
               s.sendall(data)
            print("file has sent")

Comment: Edit the question and add the code there!

Comment: yes of course it's my first time i post here sorry for this mistakes.

Comment: `command = s.recv(1024)`  ... but `s` is not defined ?  the code is incomplete.